# How to say that something rises with the fall of something else

Tags: terminology

I want to write in a math article that one parameter is going up when other is falling. These parameters are linked. What is a formal way of writing it? 
"Parameter A is rise with the fall of parameter B"?

Answer (score 16):

Going from a hunch, I would suggest "inversely proportional." If you are writing this article for a school or class you can probably get a great answer from a local math teacher or professor.

Edit: Okay, I guess I should have known that there was a technical definition of "inversely proportional." Wikipedia has a [quick description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversely_proportional#Inverse_proportionality), as do the comments here.

> For example, the time taken for a journey is inversely proportional to the speed of travel; the time needed to dig a hole is (approximately) inversely proportional to the number of people digging.

So, inversely proportional is *one type* of rising with the fall of something else. A more generic term will be more appropriate.

Comment: No: _inversely proportional_ in mathematics usually means precisely that the two parameters multiply to a constant (e.g., as `x` rises `y` goes down because `y=2/x`).

Comment: @msh210 What you are saying, and MrHen's answer, don't conflict in the least.

Comment: Thank you. I would rather have to meet with my English teacher ... :). What about: Parameter A rises with the fall of parameter B. Is it OK or I should try to come up with something else ?

Comment: @Billare Actually, it's not entirely clear: The OP's question doesn't specify the rate at which one rises and the other falls. @msh210 is correct in that inverse proportionality applies only to a constant rate. It is simpler (and possibly more accurate) to say while one increases, the other will decrease.

Comment: @Billare: the mathematical relationship given by “inversely proportional” is much more specific than “one rises as the other falls”.  For instance, suppose I’m travelling from London to Paris in a straight line.  Then the distance from London rises as the distance from Paris falls — but these are *not* inversely proportional.  This example is a relationship of the form *y = c – x* (where *c* is constant); inversely proportional means just relationships of the form *y = c/x*.

Comment: @PLL I neglected to see the word "precisely" in msh2010's answer, having just read it over.  I had realized what you were saying before, but still thought it wrong to say "no" or "wrong"; _inversely proportional_ **could** very well be the relationship the OP is seeking, though I agree it is not the most general term one could use.

Comment: @msh; @pll: I edited with a correction and a bit more information. Apologies for the mistake and confusion.

Comment: @darqer: I personally prefer [@HaL's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19607/how-to-say-that-something-rises-with-the-fall-of-something-else/19611#19611).

Comment: What about *inversely related*?

Answer (score 10):

Since it's math, you can use *increase* and *decrease*:

> Parameter A will increase as Parameter B decreases.

Using the conjunction *as* links the two parameters correlatively.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you are looking for "[negative correlation](http://www.nvcc.edu/home/elanthier/methods/correlation.htm#Negative%20correlation)"

Answer (score 6):

"decreases monotonically with" if you are being technical.

That means A **always** goes up as B goes down (there are no inflections) - but you aren't saying anything about the relationship.

Answer (score 5):

If the increasing parameter is a function of the decreasing one, then you just call it a **decreasing function** of it. (The reason for this name will be clear when you graph the increasing parameter relative to the decreasing one on a pair of axes.)

Answer (score 2):

```
A and B are 'Inversely Proportionate'
Or A is inversely proportionate to B
```

Comment: @MrHen [suggested this already](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19607/how-to-say-that-something-rises-with-the-fall-of-something-else/19609#19609); as comments/edits on his answer show, it’s not exactly correct as an answer to the question, although it might fit the OP’s specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

As one more possibility: "varies inversely".